# Неправильно формируется виджет CGridView

Tags: php, yii

### Вступление

Создаю виджет-грид в Yii, для отображения таблицы.

*Вот провайдер:*

```
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($model,
            array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'stordid=:stordid or stordid=0',
                    'params' => array(':stordid'=>$id),
                ),
            ));
```

У модели также есть **relations** но если их убрать, проблема не исчезает.

Также для виджета включены редактируемые поля:

```
    'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
```

Результат запроса - 11 записей. Записи в виджете отображаются по 10.

### Проблемы

1. При отображении на 2ой странице запись дублируется с 1ой страницы, и при этом теряется последняя 11-ая запись.
2. Дублирующая запись является одной и той же записью, т.е. при удалении удаляются обе.
3. При сортировки по другим столбцам теряются и дублируются другие записи, а иногда и ничего не теряется.

По ощущениям, виджет неправильно сортирует, или неправильно расставляет limit.

От чего это происходит, или как узнать от чего такое происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А по моим ощущениям, у вас что-то с роутами, урлами и т.д и т.п.

Все что вы перечислили делается через запрос к серверу, и либо он не воспринимается так как нужно, либо отправляется не то что нужно.